# /bin/sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am trying to get a cronjob to pipe output into a dated file in a specified (folder) location.

My crontab entry looks something like this:

```
* * * * * /some/path/test.sh >> $(date "+/home/oompah/logs/%Y%m%d.test.log")
```

What I don't understand is that when I type this command at the console, I get the correct string:

```
echo $(date "+/home/oompah/logs/%Y%m%d.test.log")
/home/oompah/logs/20110329.test.log
```

What's causing this error and how may I fix it?

bash version info is:

GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: The `$date()` call is correct - the error's most likely in your test.sh script. What's that look like?

Comment: Belongs on http://askubuntu.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: test.sh simply contains this line echo 'Hello' I don't think that is the cause of the problem

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Although I can see your point, there is a real danger of SO spreading itself so thin, that it ends up with several "specialist" sites with no more than a few dozen or tops couple of hundred people to answer questions. This question is relevant here, because although I have kept it simple (for brevity and clarity), it could very easily broaden to include questions about Python and C++, which are the tasks being run by cron.

Comment: Well, that is a discussion for meta.

Comment: this is a problem related to the shell - cron uses sh, not bash. the error message refers to /bin/sh. escaping the percents is necessary in sh, but not in bash, I think

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You should excape the percent signs in your crontab:

```
* * * * * /some/path/test.sh >> $(date "+/home/oompah/logs/\%Y\%m\%d.test.log")
```

Percent (`%`) signs have a special meaning in crontabs. They are interpreted as newline characters.

Comment: Thanks very much. This fixes the issue. I should actually have noticed this earlier as the vim editor coloring was showing that the string was not closed. Duh!. thanks anyway, you saved me an afternoon of frustration.m :)

Comment: You're welcome. I also struggled with those percent signs several times. Finally I learned it ;)

Comment: Very useful to know - just got bitten by this!

Comment: I knew the answer would hide in the email sent by cron.d, and it took me a couple of hours to fix my system to be receiving local emails delivered to /var/mail/ubuntu, and guess what the reason was: the unescaped %. Now working. Thank you guys!

Comment: this fixes the issue in Plesk too.

Answer (score 3):

Put the date command inside the script. `cron` isn't necessarily running the shell you think it is.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I want the output of the script to be sent to file. I don't relish the prospect of rewriting  the script so that all print statements are redirected to file instead of stdout - unless I am missing something? - please clarify

Comment: There's no need to have $(date ...) in the crontab. Put it inside test.sh.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have shebang `#!/bin/bash` as the first line in your script. Also, as `bmargulies` stated, put the `date` command inside the script if possible.